# Kotlin MutableStateFlow of RealmUUID? throwing exception on emitting null

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

MutableStateFlow<RealmUUID?> throws exception when trying to emit null second time.

```
@Test
fun mutableStateFlow_null_test() {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow<RealmUUID?>(null)
    runBlocking {
            this.launch {
            flow.collect {
                    println(it)
            }
        }
        for (i in 0 .. 10) {
            flow.tryEmit(null)
            delay(100)
            flow.tryEmit(RealmUUID.random())
            delay(100)
        }
    }
}
```

It throws

```
class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.Symbol cannot be cast to class io.realm.kotlin.types.RealmUUID (kotlinx.coroutines.internal.Symbol and io.realm.kotlin.types.RealmUUID are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.Symbol cannot be cast to class io.realm.kotlin.types.RealmUUID (kotlinx.coroutines.internal.Symbol and io.realm.kotlin.types.RealmUUID are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmUUIDImpl.equals(RealmUUIDImpl.kt:61)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.areEqual(Intrinsics.java:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.updateState(StateFlow.kt:329)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.setValue(StateFlow.kt:318)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.tryEmit(StateFlow.kt:370)
    at com.test.app.ExampleUnitTest$mutableStateFlow_null_test$1.invokeSuspend(ExampleUnitTest.kt:39)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:234)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
    at
```

This only happens with `MutableStateFlow<RealmUUID?>` but works fine with any primitives or data class or even with data class `TestData(val realmUUID : RealmUUID?)` and `MutableStateFlow<TestData?>(null)`

Comment: Why are you emitting null again to state flow ? there already is a null

Comment: In actual cases, it can be null or not. It throws an exception when tryEmit(null) is called second time.

Comment: I can suggest you to tie your logic not to null value - you can use 

val flow = MutableStateFlow<String>("") this approach, and work with String not With UUID, and where it is necessary you can convert it to UUID(UUID.from(string)) and vice versa myUUID.toString() and you will suffer from null values , instead you can do check for empty string